# Trying to create a class that does simple statistical calculation comes up, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, dataset, class-constructors

```
line 89, in main
    statSet.addNumber(int(n))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

when I enter my code:

```
#statistics calc

from math import sqrt

#def stat set funk.

class StatSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 0

#def get data

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

#def add num.

    def addNumber(self,x):
        if isinstance(x,(int,float)):
            data = self.data
            data.append(x)
            self.data = data
            return self
#def mean funk.

    def mean(self):
        nums = self.data

#check (if) cond.

        if len(nums)>0:
            return sum(nums)/len(nums)
        else:
            return 0

#def med funk.

    def median(self):
        nums = self.data
        nums.sort()
        length = len(nums)
        remainder = length%2
        med = 0

#if to check length

        if length == 0:
            return Non
        elif remainder ==0:
            med = (nums[length//2] + nums[length//2-1])/2
        else:
            med = nums[length//2]
        return med

#def funk stdDev

    def stdDev(self):
        data = self.data
        N = self.count()
        mean = self.mean()
        devSum = 0

        for i in range(N):
            devSum = devSum + (data[i] - mean)**2
        return sqrt(devSum)

#def count funk.

    def count(self):
        count = len(self.data)
        return count

#def min funk.

    def min(self):
        nums = self.data
        nums.sort()
        minNum = nums[0]
        return minNum

#def max funk.

    def max(self):
        nums = self.data
        nums.sort()
        maxNum = nums[-1]
        return maxNum

#main prog.

def main():

        print("Program test of StatSet class")

#class constructor

        statSet = StatSet()
        while True:
            n = input("Enter a number (to quit): ")
            if n =="":
                break
#call addnumber funk.

        statSet.addNumber(int(n))

        print("Data: ", statSet.getData())
        print("Mean: ", statSet.mean())
        print("Median: ", statSet.median())
        print("Standard deviation: ", statSet.stdDev())
        print("Min: ", statSet.min())
        print("Max: ", statSet.max())
        print("Data: ", statSet.getData())
        print("Count: ", statSet.count())

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this loop:

```py
    while True:
        n = input("Enter a number (to quit): ")
        if n =="":
            break
```

You are overwriting `n`, and only breaking out of the loop when `n==""`.

After that, you're trying to parse `n` (which is `""`) as an `int`, which fails, as expected.

Remove the loop and it will work:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Comment: I'm sure I am making a simple mistake. But, when I do that it sticks me in an infinite enter number loop with no outcome.

Comment: That's because you had an infinite `while` loop. Remove the entire loop.

Comment: i did that at first but it returned "line 18, in addNumber
    data.append(x)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'" so I put it back in, and thats when I got the infinite entry

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it fixed. The problem was in my initial values:

```
#def stat set funk.

class StatSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

#def get data

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

#def add num.

    def addNumber(self,x):
        if isinstance(x,(int,float)):
            self.data.append(x)
            return self
```